# Why am I getting an error? (syntax error, unexpected keyword_true)

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

This is the errors I am getting :

> banking.rb:110: syntax error, unexpected keyword_true, expecting
>   keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
>       if transfer_valid?=true then
>                              ^ banking.rb:115: warning: else without rescue is useless

Here is my code:

```
#---------------BANK ACCOUNT CLASS---------------#
class BankAccount
  def initialize(name, balance=1000, status="open")
    @name=name
    @balance=balance
    @status=status
  end

#Change name
  def name=(name)
    @name=name
  end

#Returns account name
  def name
    @name
  end

#Sets account status
  def status=(status)
    @status=status
  end

#Method lets you deposit money to account
  def deposit(amount)
    @balance+=amount.to_i
  end

#Method lets you set your balance
  def balance=(balance)
    @balance=balance
  end

#Returns your balance
  def balance
    @balance
  end

#Method displays the balance
  def display_balance
    return "Your Balance is $#{@balance}."
  end

#Method checks if account is valid
  def valid?
    if balance>0 and status=="open" then
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

#Method closes the account
  def close_account
    @status="closed"
  end

#Method returns the status of the account
  def status
    return "@status"      
  end

#---------------TRANSFER CLASS---------------#
class Transfer
  def initialize(sender, receiver, funds)
    @sender=sender
    @receiver=receiver
    @funds=funds
    @status="pending"

#WILL NEED TO FIGURE OUT A WAY FOR IT TO WORK FOR EVERY ACCOUNT
    @sender_funds=sender_account_name.balance
    @sender_account_status=sender_account_name.status

    @receiver_funds=receiver_account_name.funds
    @receiver_account_status=receiver_account_name.status
  end

 #Returns sender account name 
  def sender
    @sender
  end

#Change receiver
  def receiver=(receiver)
    @receiver=receiver
  end

 #Returns receiver account name 
  def receiver
    @receiver
  end

#Returns tranfer status
  def status
    @status
  end

#Returns if accounts are valid for transfer
  def transfer_valid?
    if @sender_account_status=="open" && @receiver_account_status=="open" && @sender_funds-@funds>=0
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

#Transfers the money
  def transfer
    if transfer_valid?=true then
      @receiver_funds+=@funds
      @sender_funds-=@funds
    else
      @status="failed"
    end
  end

#Returns sender account funds after transfer
  def sender_funds_after_transfer
    @sender_funds
  end
#Returns receiver account funds after transfer
  def receiver_funds_after_transfer
    @receiver_funds
  end
end


#------------FOR TEST-------------#
puts "Enter the sender_account_name"
sender_account_name=gets.chomp.lowcase
sender_account_name=BankAccount.new(sender_account_name)

puts "Enter the receiver_account_name"
receiver_account_name=gets.chomp.lowcase
receiver_account_name=BankAccount.new(receiver_account_name)

puts "Sender has #{sender_account_name.balance}$ in his account."
puts "Receiver has #{receiver_account_name.balance}$ in his account."

#Makes the transfer
first_transfer=Transfers.new(sender_account_name, receiver_account_name, 20)

#Return account funds
puts "Sender has #{sender_account_name.sender_funds_after_transfer}$ in his account."
puts "Receiver has #{receiver_account_name.receiver_funds_after_transfer}$ in his account."
```

I might be calling the method inside the class in an incorrect way. I am new to classes so I do not exactly know how I should be doing it.

Thank you very much for answer and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if transfer_valid?=true then
```

change to

```
if transfer_valid?
```